# How does an Eclipse 4 Application deploy user accessible files

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I create an Eclipse 4 Application. From a button widget in a Part or a menu item handler, I want to allow the user to browse an included directory and access files for viewing and editing. However the product deployment to multiple platforms deploys it as a plug-in jar and the directory and files are not visible.

I've seen comments that if one has a feature project, one can select an option to explode the jar on deployment. However, the project creation wizard creates only a plug-in project when you select "Eclipse 4 Application Project", and does not allow you to create it as a feature project.

If I am forced to go the feature route, given I already have my Eclipse 4 Application Project with its application model, do I have to start from scratch with a feature project and recreate the application model manually (i.e. re declare all the Parts one at a time)?

Is there a  way to just deploy the user accessible files effectively outside the classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

to the MANIFEST.MF of a plugin to get it built as a directory.

However this directory will be part of the RCP plugins directory. It is probably not a good idea to let the user edit things there. It would be better if you copied the files to be edited to a some other location.

Converting a product based on plugins to a feature based product is quite straightforward.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree with you that I don't want the user editing files in the plug-ins directory. So that's out.

Comment: In which case you will have to add code to copy the files somewhere else, there is nothing in e4 which will do that for you

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree with you that I don't want the user editing files in the plug-ins directory. So that's out. Still not sure about converting it to a feature-based product given the investment in the application model. Can the existing Application.e4xmi file simply be manually copied across or how else can it be reused? Thanks!

Comment: Feature based doesn't get you anything here - the expand in a feature does exactly the same thing as Eclipse-BundleShape. For a feature build you just create a feature project and add your plugins to the feature.xml. You then change the .product file to list your feature and the Eclipse features you want. The rest of the code is unchanged.

Comment: OK, you've saved me some painful & time-consuming experimenting, I'll go with copying in parallel. I'm just surprised that the export wizard doesn't do this given it is a product (not "just" a plug-in). Thanks again.